# Understand and troubleshoot SIGILL

Tags: c++, arm, illegal-instruction

I have built a copy of rocksdb for erlang (gitlab.com/Vagabond1/erlang-rocksdb@8708fe8) for a armv7 based target. It's a iMX6 SoloX processor, here's the cpuinfo:

```
processor       : 0
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 10 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 7.54
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpd32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x2
CPU part        : 0xc09
CPU revision    : 10

Hardware        : Freescale i.MX6 SoloX (Device Tree)
Revision        : 0500
```

I have a program that loads the compiled `liberocksdb.so` but it crashes with a SIGILL, here's the back trace:

```
#0  0xb1b2a7b0 in std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing::operator()(unsigned int, unsigned int) const () from /opt/miner/lib/rocksdb-1.5.0/priv/liberocksdb.so
#1  0xb1b79b48 in std::__detail::_Hash_code_base<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, rocksdb::OptionsSanityCheckLevel>, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::hash<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, true>::_M_bucket_index(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int, unsigned int) const () from /opt/miner/lib/rocksdb-1.5.0/priv/liberocksdb.so
#2  0xb1b751d4 in std::_Hashtable<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, rocksdb::OptionsSanityCheckLevel>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, rocksdb::OptionsSanityCheckLevel> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::hash<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, false, true> >::_M_bucket_index(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int) const ()
   from /opt/miner/lib/rocksdb-1.5.0/priv/liberocksdb.so
#3  0xb1b6e01c in std::pair<std::__detail::_Node_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, rocksdb::OptionsSanityCheckLevel>, false, true>, bool> std::_Hashtable<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, rocksdb::OptionsSanityCheckLevel>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, rocksdb::OptionsSanityCheckLevel> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::hash<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, false, true> >::_M_insert<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, rocksdb::OptionsSanityCheckLevel> const&, std::__detail::_AllocNode<std::allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, rocksdb::OptionsSanityCheckLevel>, true> > > >(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, rocksdb::OptionsSanityCheckLevel> const&, std::__detail::_AllocNode<std::allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, rocksdb::OptionsSanityCheckLevel>, true> > > const&, std::integral_constant<bool, true>) () from /opt/miner/lib/rocksdb-1.5.0/priv/liberocksdb.so
#4  0xb1b63edc in std::__detail::_Insert_base<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, rocksdb::OptionsSanityCheckLevel>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, rocksdb::OptionsSanityCheckLevel> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::hash<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, false, true> >::insert(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, rocksdb::OptionsSanityCheckLevel> const&) ()
   from /opt/miner/lib/rocksdb-1.5.0/priv/liberocksdb.so
#5  0xb1b568b8 in std::_Hashtable<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, rocksdb::OptionsSanityCheckLevel>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, rocksdb::OptionsSanityCheckLevel> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::hash<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, false, true> >::_Hashtable<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, rocksdb::OptionsSanityCheckLevel> const*>(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, rocksdb::OptionsSanityCheckLevel> const*, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, rocksdb::OptionsSanityCheckLevel> const*, unsigned int, std::hash<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > const&, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing const&, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash const&, std::equal_to<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > const&, std::__detail::_Select1st const&, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, rocksdb::OptionsSanityCheckLevel> > const&) () from /opt/miner/lib/rocksdb-1.5.0/priv/liberocksdb.so
#6  0xb1b489fc in std::_Hashtable<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, rocksdb::OptionsSanityCheckLevel>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, rocksdb::OptionsSanityCheckLevel> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::hash<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, false, true> >::_Hashtable(std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, rocksdb::OptionsSanityCheckLevel> >, unsigned int, std::hash<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > const&, std::equal_to<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > const&, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, rocksdb::OptionsSanityCheckLevel> > const&) () from /opt/miner/lib/rocksdb-1.5.0/priv/liberocksdb.so
#7  0xb1b3c10c in std::unordered_map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, rocksdb::OptionsSanityCheckLevel, std::hash<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::equal_to<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, rocksdb::OptionsSanityCheckLevel> > >::unordered_map(std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, rocksdb::OptionsSanityCheckLevel> >, unsigned int, std::hash<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > const&, std::equal_to<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > const&, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, rocksdb::OptionsSanityCheckLevel> > const&) () from /opt/miner/lib/rocksdb-1.5.0/priv/liberocksdb.so
#8  0xb1b28b04 in __static_initialization_and_destruction_0 () from /opt/miner/lib/rocksdb-1.5.0/priv/liberocksdb.so
#9  0xb1b29d30 in _GLOBAL__sub_I_db_impl.cc () from /opt/miner/lib/rocksdb-1.5.0/priv/liberocksdb.so
#10 0xb6fddff8 in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

Here's the disassembly:

```
(gdb) disas /m
Dump of assembler code for function _ZNKSt8__detail18_Mod_range_hashingclEjj:
   0xb1b2a790 <+0>:     push    {r11}           ; (str r11, [sp, #-4]!)
   0xb1b2a794 <+4>:     add     r11, sp, #0
   0xb1b2a798 <+8>:     sub     sp, sp, #20
   0xb1b2a79c <+12>:    str     r0, [r11, #-8]
   0xb1b2a7a0 <+16>:    str     r1, [r11, #-12]
   0xb1b2a7a4 <+20>:    str     r2, [r11, #-16]
   0xb1b2a7a8 <+24>:    ldr     r3, [r11, #-12]
   0xb1b2a7ac <+28>:    ldr     r2, [r11, #-16]
=> 0xb1b2a7b0 <+32>:    udiv    r2, r3, r2
   0xb1b2a7b4 <+36>:    ldr     r1, [r11, #-16]
   0xb1b2a7b8 <+40>:    mul     r2, r1, r2
   0xb1b2a7bc <+44>:    sub     r3, r3, r2
   0xb1b2a7c0 <+48>:    mov     r0, r3
   0xb1b2a7c4 <+52>:    add     sp, r11, #0
   0xb1b2a7c8 <+56>:    pop     {r11}           ; (ldr r11, [sp], #4)
   0xb1b2a7cc <+60>:    bx      lr
End of assembler dump.
```

I am not an expert in this domain, but as far as I understand, the program crashed because the instruction `udiv` is illegal for my CPU.
I've checked ARM developer website, this is a [Cortex M3 instruction](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0337/h/programmers-model/instruction-set-summary/cortex-m3-instructions) and I believe that my CPU is [Cortex M4](https://www.nxp.com/products/processors-and-microcontrollers/arm-processors/i-mx-applications-processors/i-mx-6-processors/i-mx-6solox-processors-heterogeneous-processing-with-arm-cortex-a9-and-cortex-m4-cores:i.MX6SX), so I guess it should have this instruction?

Perhaps my analysis is wrong and this is something else?

My cross compilation was made with the cross toolchain for that CPU and rootfs, and contained arguments such as `-march=armv7-a -marm -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard` which should provide compatible binaries.

Thanks

Comment: The way you formulated your question confuses me. The i.MX 6SoloX is a multi-core system with a Cortex®-A9 (not a Cortex®-A7), and a Cortex®-M4. So, any program compiled with `-march=armv7-a -marm -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard` should only be executed on the  Cortex®-A9 , and programs compiled with `-march=armv7-m -mtune=cortex-m4`  should only be executed on the  Cortex®-M4. You may have a mismatch between compiler options/programs/cores here.

Comment: I've reach my knowledge limits here. How is the core picked when executing a program? Does this mean that Linux ran the program on the A9 and it tried to run an instruction designed for the M4? How can I have the program run on the M4? The code that generates this SIGILL is not mine, it's from the rocksdb dependency.

Comment: Perhaps Linux itself runs only on the A9? Then how is the M4 used? I know my question is not very precisely formulated, but I'm trying to make this program work on my target and I'm not the one that designed it and I have little experience with CPU, instructions and cross compilation.

Comment: This almost 100% sure that that Linux is only running on the Cortex-A9. What is exactly your target ? the CortexA9 running a Linux application ? I would assume this is the case, but could you please be more explicit ?

Comment: NXP does provide the software support for executing, say, a FreeRTOS application on the Cortex-M4. You will have to refer to the NXP documentation for more details on how.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations, it helps a lot. My target is A9 for a linux application. I compiled with `-march=armv7-a -marm -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard` so I don't see why the generated .so contains an instruction that targets Cortex-M...

Comment: I would suggest to augment your question with the version of g++ you are using, as well as the exact procedure you followed for compiling  rocksdb , so that others may build it the exact same way you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cmake script forced the use of `-march=armv8-a+crc` which is not compatible with my CPU.

https://gitlab.com/Vagabond1/erlang-rocksdb/-/commit/6bf4a440b8132ef643682ba87dee6de87dc47d58